# PHP : Best way to create array from textarea of variables

Tags: php

I have a textarea where users can put variables like this :

```
VARIABLE=foo
RANDOM=iloveit
GREAT=amazing
```

I need to transform this in an array of parameters.

So i did this function (who works) :

```
public static function cleanWebhookTextarea($textareaLines){

        $textareaLines = preg_split('/(;|,|\r\n,|\r,|\n)/', $textareaLines);
        $params = array();

        foreach ($textareaLines as $line){
            $line = preg_split('/(=)/', $line);
            $params[$line[0]] = $line[1];   
        }

        return $params;

    }
```

This return me what i want, so :

```
array:3 [▼
  "VARIABLE" => "foo"
  "RANDOM" => "iloveit"
  "GREAT" => "amazin"
]
```

But i wondering if there is a quickest way to do what i want ?

Thanks

Comment: This seems like a good way to do it, given that a textbox is required: Newline, semicolon or comma to terminate each statement, ```=``` to mark key-value pairs. Alternatively you could create paired input fields for keys and their values.

Comment: I hope=you've=got=a=**LOT**`\r\n`of=+error=trapping`\t`in=there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you can do it in one line with function like [str_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) and [parse_str](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php)

```
parse_str(str_replace(PHP_EOL, '&', $data), $result);
```

Here is a [working example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0a20e19e7b216593cf3555bc579dc010fd1ad730).

Comment: Amazing ! I was pretty sure it's possible to optimize. But not expecting so much !
Thanks